# Why thano does not update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, theano

I'm tying to resolve the follow problem: a theano function has as outputs the value that a class method return after has made a while loop, within which a parameter is updated:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np
import copy
theano.config.exception_verbosity = 'high'

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rate=0.01
        W_val=40.00
        self.W=theano.shared(value=W_val, borrow=True)
    def start(self, x, y):
        for i in range(5):
            z=T.mean(x*self.W/y)
            gz=T.grad(z, self.W)
            self.W-=self.rate*gz
        return z

x_set=np.array([1.,2.,1.,2.,1.,2.,1.,2.,1.,2.])
y_set=np.array([1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2])
x_set = theano.shared(x_set, borrow=True)
y_set = theano.shared(y_set, borrow=True)
y_set=T.cast(y_set, 'int32')
batch_size=2

x = T.dvector('x')
y = T.ivector('y')
index = T.lscalar()

test = Test()
cost=test.start(x,y)

train = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=cost,
    givens={
        x: x_set[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: y_set[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)

for i in range(5):
    result=train(i)
    print(result)
```

this is the result of the print:

```
39.96000000089407
39.96000000089407
39.96000000089407
39.96000000089407
39.96000000089407
```

Now the gradient of mean(x*W/y) is equal to 1 (because x and y always have the same value). So the first time i should have 39.95, than 39.90 and so on...
Why i always have the same result??

Thanks

Comment: In your start loop. in every iteration you overwrite your z variable, cannot that be the reason?

Comment: @PepaKorbel: i have to overwrite z, but i update the value of W, so the value of z must change, didn't it?

Comment: Oh ye i double checked that, you are updatings your weights using that z variable. That have to be somewhere else

Comment: @PepaKorbel Yes but where?? I am going crazy...

Comment: Your x and y tensor are identical?

Comment: @PepaKorbel This code is a semplifcation of a more complex code (that i can never post because is thousands of line), the value of x, y are chosen to be the same to semplify my uderstanding of what is happening. It seems that the value of W are computed one time (the first) and never updated, but why?

Comment: And cannot that be the reason? Because if look at it in theory, if your input is identical is desired output, it might somehow backpropagate once and update weights (thats the 39.9 you got, once update weight which started at 40) and then just stop, because there is no need to backpropagate if you have 100% accuracy

Comment: @PepaKorbel Ok i've uderstand your point, but who tell him to stop if the accurancy is 100%? I've change the value of y in [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1], now i have always another number: 49.937500001396984. I don't know much of how theano working, but seems that start method is executed one time, only when is called, before the train function is declared, so outside the for loop. When i call the train inside the for loop it does not update W. But i still don't uderstand why.

Comment: I think this problem is unsolvable in this way, i have to use thano function and "updates". But i yet know i'll have problems, if same one is interested can help me to resolve the problem in an another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872177/theano-missinginputerror

Comment: When you are backpropagating using cross-entropy for example, you are taking derivative of that slope which gives you the direction in which you update the weights, if you are already on the bottom, there is nowhere to go to get better results. Try addings logs or prints to your code to see what and when and how many times is executed.

Comment: @PepaKorbel i add a print(0) inside the loop of start method, print('call start') before cost=test.start(x,y), and a print('start called') after. this is the catastrophic result:call start
0
0
0
0
0
start called
49.937500001396984
49.937500001396984
49.937500001396984
49.937500001396984
49.937500001396984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've result with the help of friend Pascal from [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/rZ7K4pNT628). The solution is to create an other symbolic variables:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rate=0.01
        W_val=40.00
        self.W=theano.shared(value=W_val, borrow=True)
    def start(self, x, y):
        new_W=self.W
        for i in range(5):
            z=T.mean(x*new_W/y)
            gz=T.grad(z, new_W)
            new_W-=self.rate*gz
        return z, (self.W, new_W)
```

and modify the theano function:

```
test = Test()
cost, updates=test.start(x,y)

train = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=cost,
    updates=[updates],
    givens={
        x: x_set[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: y_set[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)
```

The output:

```
39.96000000089407
39.91000000201166
39.860000003129244
39.81000000424683
39.76000000536442
```